# Qual a diferença entre as formas de pesquisa LINQ com Datetime.Now?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

Estou executando dois trechos de códigos e estão dando resultados diferentes. Alguém sabe o porquê?

Esse código mostra cupons apenas que possuem a validade da data e hora atual + 3h (não sei porque):

```
var cupons = Listar().Where(c => c.Validade > Datetime.Now);
```

Enquanto que esse código mostra os cupons corretamente:

```
Datetime agora = Datetime.Now;
var cupons = Listar().Where(c => c.Validade > agora);
```

OBS: A função Listar consulta no banco de dados.

Comment: Com o é indicado `apenas que possuem a validade da data e hora atual + 3h` o problema é a diferença de horários entre onde o código é executado e a base de dados. Experimente usar `Datetime.UtcNow`.

Comment: conseguiu verificar o problema?

Comment: O problema era a diferença de horários entre o servidor que estava executando o código e a hora da base de dados (os fusos estavam diferentes mesmo). Para resolver eu utilizei a 2° abordagem, pois ela filtra a lista com o horário do servidor (que era o certo). 
A 1° abordagem converte o Datetime.Now para um select que consulta a hora da base de dados. No caso do postgres, o Datetime.Now era convertido para 'select current_timestamp;'
Obrigada pelas respostas!

Comment: Neste caso, pode marcar a resposta como aceita e votar nas que achou relevante. [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Não se esqueça de votar nas respostas que achar relevantes e aceitar a que resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De início a pergunta não estava clara, agora estou destacando esta parte depois da edição porque o problema é este. A segunda parte fica como complemento para as pessoas entenderem melhor o LINQ.

## Busca em banco de dados

Se o dado está em um banco de dados (a pergunta não fala nada sobre isto) a e expressão será traduzia para ser executada no banco de dados e dependendo do provedor utilizado o `DateTime.Now` será traduzido para uma expressão que ele reconhece e será executado lá no banco de dados que pode estar com fuso horário diferente da aplicação. Nada disso é garantido, mas costuma acontecer. Quando pega uma variável da aplicação essa tradução não é possível e aí ele compara com o dado fixo da do momento que é mandado para o banco de dados.

Até acho que isto é um outro erro porque os horários deveriam ser todos UTC e nunca ter problema de fuso, mas não é o foco da pergunta. Provavelmente o erro é de modelagem que adotou fuso horário no armazenamento.

## Outro erro comum com LINQ

O primeiro está usando uma expressão que compara um dado da coleção de dados sendo avaliada com o horário do momento. Conforme vai passando o tempo esse momento muda. Em cada verificação de um elemento da coleção o valor de `Datetime.Now` muda, então neste exemplo tende a filtrar um pouco mais por ter uma valor móvel, ele vai estreitando.

O segundo pega o momento atual da execução do código e guarda em uma variável. Esse valor é fixo, ele não muda mais. Aí quando percorre a coleção de dados a comparação está sendo feita sempre com o mesmo valor, o valor não estreita, não muda durante a execução.

Mas o LINQ ainda tem uma característica que agrava mais o problema. Essa tecnologia usa uma técnica chamada *lazy evaluation*. Quando você executa esta linha de código nada está sendo executado de verdade. Somente quando precisa do dado ou materializa o coleção de dados é que a execução será feita. Isto pode ser feito segundos, minutos ou horas depois em alguns casos. Inclusive o tempo entre verificar um elemento e outro pode demorar bastante. Não é tão comum, mas pode acontecer.

Dá para perceber como os resultados podem ser bem diferentes? Um deles sempre usará o tempo do momento da efetiva execução de um elemento, porque você usou um código que manda pegar um tempo novo cada vez que passa por ele. O outro pega um tempo e guarda, aí toda vez que avaliar um elemento mesmo que muito tempo depois o tempo a ser usado é sempre o mesmo, é aquele que pegou logo no início da execução.

Eu gosto do LINQ, mas vejo um problema nele porque as pessoas e não entendem o que ele é, acham que há mágica dentro dele e que não precisar entender nada dessa "mágica" toda. Sem entender profundamente o LINQ eu acho que as pessoas não deveriam usá-lo.

Se você escrevesse esses códigos na mão talvez desse pra perceber melhor porque acontece isso:

```
foreach (var c in Lista()) {
    if (c.Validade > DateTime.Now) {
        //faz alguma coisa
    }
    //talvez chama algo aqui demorado
}
```

E

```
var agora = DateTIme.Now;
foreach (var c in Lista()) {
    if (c.Validade > agora) {
        //faz alguma coisa, poderia montar uma outra lista, mas seria a materialização
    }
    //talvez chama algo aqui demorado
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/VariableOut.cs).

## LINQ não é simples

E um dos problemas que mais vejo as pessoas fazerem com LINQ é usar um `ToList()` para materializar a coleção de dados. Quando a pessoa faz isso provavelmente ela não deveria usar o LINQ, a vantagem desta técnica é justamente não materializar sem necessidade e se tiver necessidade sempre, então o LINQ não ajuda tanto quanto poderia. No caso você provavelmente está acessando a coleção de dados sem materializar a toa e isto é bom, mas também é o causador da diferença.

## Conclusão

Qual dá o resultado esperado? Vá com ele. Eu acho que o segundo é melhor na maioria dos casos, mas vejo cenário onde o primeiro é mais útil. Ou conserte o erro de modelagem.

Comment: Era o problema do fuso horário com o banco de dados! Eu me esqueci de especificar na pergunta que a consulta era em um banco de dados, já editei ela! Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Imagino que `Listar` execute uma query na base de dados. Sendo o caso, quando feito o `Where`, o linq adiciona as condições à query enviada para a base, que *não* deve ter o fuso horário brasileiro (-3 horas).

No outro caso, a data adicionada à query é a do seu computador, que deve ter o fuso horário.

Uma forma de evitar este tipo de problema é sempre usar as datas em `UTC` e convertê-las somente quando necessário.